# See information of partitions of a Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

One can have an array of partitions of a Spark `DataFrame` as follows:

```
> df.rdd.partitions
```

Is there a way to get more information about partitions? In particular, I would like to see the partition key and the partition boundaries (first and last element within a partition).

This is just for better understanding of how the data is organized.

This is what I tried:

```
> df.partitions.rdd.head
```

But this object only has attributes and methods `equals` `hashCode` and `index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the data is not too large, one can write them to disk as follows:

```
df.write.option("header", "true").csv("/tmp/foobar")
```

The given directory must not exist.